# Automatically render None as null in template?

Tags: python, django

I am rendering a template with `message` bundled in the `context`. Sometimes the `message` will be `None`:

```py
def context_test(request):
    context = {
      'message': None,
    }
    return render(request, 'testapp/context_test.html', context)
```

I want to alert the message on front-end only if it is not `None`. So far I am doing it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
    let message = "{{ message }}";
    {% if message %}
    alert(message);
    {% endif %}
</script>

</html>
```

However, I would like to replace the Django's `if` clause with pure Javascript, like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
    let message = "{{ message }}";  // or {{ message }} ?
    if (message) {
        alert(message);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

In order for this to work, I would need `message` equal to `null` (or other falsy value) in the script.

Can it be done in a clean way, without an additional conversion in the script like `if {message === 'None'} message = null`? In other words, can I somehow tell Django to automatically render context's `None` as `null` in the template?

Comment: How about using `json.dumps` to convert it into valid Javascript?

Comment: you need to use json.dumps `json.dumps(None)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `default_if_none` to make None look more JavaScript like.

```js
let message = '{{ message|default_if_none: "false" }}';
if (message != 'false') {
    alert(message);
}
```